# Which way of struct initalization is better in C

Tags: c

There are 2 ways of struct init in C, and I wonder if there is significant difference in code culture.

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    
};

struct myStruct myVar = {4,5};
```

or

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    
}myStruct;

myStruct myVar = {4,5};
```

Which one is more common used in practice?

Comment: Your question seems to be about declaration, not initialization.

Comment: The initialization is the same in each case.  One has a typedef.  There is no need to typedef a struct and doing so generally obfuscates the code.  Unfortunately, it is extremely common.

Comment: Yes, sorry guys you are right it's about declaration obviously.

Comment: You will not get a definitive answer to this question, as it's basically a matter of opinion, a subjective issue of style.  Some people will tell you that the typedef is generally unnecessary.  Some people will tell you that the typedef is fine, that's the way everyone does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is more common. There is no significant difference in real life.

Comment: I disagree that the first one is more common.   I almost exclusively see `typedef`s, not "raw" structure declarations.

Comment: @abelenky I expect you know this, but the typedef form is popular because it's the appropriate compromise idiom when you're programming in the C/C++ language, as lots of people (imagine that they) are.